# Simplifying an expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, radicals

I've been trying to simplify this expression for quite a long time but I just can't get to the result given in the book. The result in the book says that this expression should be simplified to (a*b; a>0, b>0, a not equal to b).
[image: The expression to be simplified]

> $$\left(\sqrt{ab}-\frac{ab}{a+\sqrt{ab}}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{ab}-\sqrt[4]b}{a-b}\right)^{-1}
> \cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]a+\sqrt[4]b}{\sqrt[4]{b^3}}\right)^{-1}$$

Can anyone help me with this task?

Comment: Perhaps the first $\sqrt[4]{b}$ should be $\sqrt{b}$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression does **not** simplify to *ab*. In order for that to happen, we must have $\sqrt b$ instead of $\sqrt[4]b$ in the second parenthesis, as it has already been pointed out by **Michael** in the comment section.